# Going to Japan for 2 weeks, vaccinations

Tags: japan, health

I am going to Fukuoka in southern Japan for a 2-week holiday. Is there an official site that states what vaccinations I should get before my trip?

Comment: I think this depends on where you are from. Here in Denmark, we have a site for this specific purpose. For Japan, there are several comon diseases to be vaccinated against, but people here are usually already vaccinated in school or from previous trips. Other countries probably have similar sites.

Comment: @Nix Very convenient, I am also from Denmark. Which site are you referring to?

Comment: Vaccinations for Japan???? Niger, please!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are from **Denmark** (like OP and I), there is a very handy site called [rejsedoktor.dk](http://www.rejsedoktor.dk/vaccinations/japan.123.html#1).

For a two-week trip to Japan, you need the following vaccinations:

- diphtheria
- hepatitis A
- tetanus

It is likely that you already have one or more of these vaccinations. Diphteria and tetanus are usually administered together at public school, and lasts for ten years. Hepatitis A lasts for one year, but if you get a follow-up shot within that year, it lasts for 25 years (though my doctor said "for life" – I guess he knows something about my medical conditions that I don't. Hmmm.).

Similar Danish sites:
[sikkerrejse.dk](http://www.sikkerrejse.dk/), [blivvaccineret.dk](http://blivvaccineret.dk/vaccinationer/asien/japan/) and in some cases simply [netdoktor.dk](http://www.netdoktor.dk/).

**Sweden** have similar sites:
[resemedicin.com](http://www.resemedicin.com/Vaccinationsguiden/Resm%C3%A5l.aspx) and [vaccinationsguiden.se](http://www.vaccinationsguiden.se/vaccinationsguiden/default.asp).

**Norway**:
[nettdoktor.no](http://www.nettdoktor.no/reisemedisin/land/asia/japan.php)

Finally, you can some times find info about this on your country's official travel guides, although they are primarilly for emergencies and security warnings.

Comment: It is quite funny that the Norwegian and Swedish sites don't say anything about Hepatitis A. But thanks for the links.

Comment: Hmm, yes, and they mention polio instead. I think you should simply ask your doctor.

Answer (score 3):

There aren't any requirements from most countries. There are recommendations for some. For example: Japanese encephalitis if you're spending lots of time outdoors.

A list for Canadians: http://travel.gc.ca/travelling/publications/well-on-your-way

Comment: Japanese encephalitis is, despite its name, barely existent in Japan. For a very long stay with daily access to cattle (mosquitoes are the vector), it might make sense. Otherwise, no.

Answer (score 0):

None. I've lived in Japan for 12 years, never once heard of vaccination requirements nor been asked a single question about it at the airport. I expect it depends on where you are from, but there's nothing here of any particular concern.

(But stay out of the Dengue Fever park in Tokyo.)